# sql performance when executing huge table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

i found this sql file at my workplace

```
DECLARE

 M_DEPATURE_TIME    varchar;

BEGIN

  SELECT min(cast(to_char(i.departuredate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') as varchar) ||' '|| i.departuretime) as deptime
  INTO M_DEPATURE_TIME
  FROM myschema.flightinfosv i

  WHERE upper(i.inout) = upper(m_inout)
  AND  i.r_id= m_resconfirmid;

  RETURN M_DEPATURE_TIME;

END;
```

The problem is why this script will take more time(more than 15 mins) to execute in thousands of records table.The table(resflightinfosv) consist of at least 50,000 records.Although i use indexes for both 'inout' and 'r_id' and when execute with even 1000 limit it will take that time.Where are the places I need to change this script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: index the departuredate field, and move the min() **INSIDE** the conversion, so you're not forcing the db to do a ton of useless string formatting, which then simply gets thrown away once you find the min. find the min date FIRST, THEN you format it.

Comment: Is that the exact query are have you changed it? I can't imagine scanning a 50,000 row table taking 15 minutes. (Or do you mean that you execute it 50,000 times and *that* takes 15 mins?)

Comment: Unfortunately no matter how you slice it, even after removing the unneeded string formatting, it's still probably going to run rather slow, as casting in SQL is a rather slow process.  Shouldn't be fifteen minutes slow though.

Comment: @MarcB why should I index departuredate field?

Comment: Is this for oracle? Assuming that you have added the indexes, maybe this will be a little better: `SELECT cast(to_char(x.departuredate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') as varchar) ||' '|| x.departuretime FROM (SELECT departuredate,departuretime FROM myschema.flightinfosv i WHERE upper(i.inout) = upper(m_inout) AND  i.r_id= m_resconfirmid) ORDER BY departuredate, departuretime) x WHERE x.rownum = 1 `

Comment: @bews99, maybe is costly the strings conversions within MIN, try to get out in other query, check the query that i posted you.

Comment: BTW: storing date and tiome in two separate columns won't win you the Nobel prize either.

Comment: This `cast(to_char(i.departuredate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') as varchar)` seems redundant...no?

Comment: do you have index on `r_id, inout`? is `upper(i.inout)` absolutely necessary or you can use just `i.inout`?

Comment: @RomanPekar i can remove `upper`.but i don't think it is a big failure

Comment: @GastonF. thanks.i will check that soon.

Comment: @bews99, change `WHERE x.rownum = 1` for LIMIT 1...I thought it was oracle.

Comment: You can remove the `CAST` cause `cast(to_char(i.departuredate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') as varchar)` is redundant. Use only `to_char(i.departuredate,'DD-Mon-YYYY')` instead

Comment: @bews99 what about index on r_id, inout?

Comment: they are simple indexes CRAETE UNIQUE INDEX idx_rid ON flightinfosv (rid,inout)

Comment: @bews99 if your index is unique, why do you need `min`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a multi-column index on `departuredate` and `departuretime` and try something like this; extract the minimum date first and then, for this date, select the smallest hour. I don't think that the following code will work "as-is" cause I'm not able to test it but you get the main idea :)

```
DECLARE

 M_DEPATURE_DATE    date,
 M_DEPATURE_TIME    varchar;

BEGIN

  SELECT min(i.departuredate) as depdate
  INTO M_DEPATURE_DATE
  FROM myschema.flightinfosv i
  WHERE upper(i.inout) = upper(m_inout)
  AND  i.r_id= m_resconfirmid;

  SELECT to_char(i.departuredate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') ||' '|| min(i.departuretime) as deptime
  INTO M_DEPATURE_TIME
  FROM myschema.flightinfosv i

  WHERE upper(i.inout) = upper(m_inout)
  AND  i.r_id= m_resconfirmid
  AND  i.departuredate = M_DEPATURE_DATE

  RETURN M_DEPATURE_TIME;

END;
```